# How to display product by using order Item_Id in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product

I'm trying to show product detail by order Item_Id. I have this page:

[image]

When we click on **Order Detail**, it will get the item (**2**) to show product detail we've chosen. Here is my code to show this page:

```
<?php 
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $orders        = $objectManager-> 
    create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item')->getCollection();

    echo "<p style='color:red; 
             font-size:20px;'>
             Product Ordered
         </p>";
 ?>
  <div class="table-wrapper orders-history">
       <table class="data table table-order-items history" id="my-orders- 
        table">
        <caption class="table-caption"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Orders')) 
      ?></caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" class="col orderitemid"> <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('OrderItem'    )) ?></th>
      <th scope="col" class="col image      "> <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Product Image')) ?></th>
      <th scope="col" class="col name       "> <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Product Name' )) ?></th>
      <th scope="col" class="col Qty        "> <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty'          )) ?></th>
      <th scope="col" class="col Price      "> <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Price'        )) ?></th>
      <th scope="col" class="col Total      "> <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Total'        )) ?></th>
      <th scope="col" class="col Action     "> <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Action'       )) ?></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
<tbody>
  <?php foreach($orders as $item): ?>
    <?php 
     $_product     = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($item->getProductId());
     $imageHelper  = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
     $image_url    = $imageHelper->init($_product, 'product_page_image_small')->setImageFile($_product->getImage())->resize(100, 100)->getUrl();
    ?>
      <tr>
        <td data-th="OrderItem    "class="col orderitemid">  <?php echo $item->getItemId();           ?></td>
        <td data-th="Product Image"class="col image   ">  <img src="<?= $image_url ?>"  width="75px" height="75px"></td>
        <td data-th="Product Name "class="col name    ">  <?php echo $item->getName();                ?></td>
        <td data-th="Qty          "class="col qty     ">  <?php echo $item->getQtyOrdered();          ?></td>
        <td data-th="Price        "class="col price   ">  <?php echo $item->getPrice();               ?></td>
        <td data-th="Subtotal     "class="col subtotal">  <?php echo $item->getBaseRowTotalInclTax(); ?></td>

        <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Actions')) ?>" class="col actions">
          <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('history/detail/display',['item_id' => $item->getItemId()]); ?>">Order Detail</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
```

Can anyone help the next step?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: You want to redirect to product page?

Comment: Hi @Rohan. Could you tell me how can I get productUrl to redirect to product page??

Comment: Please check my answer. using that you can get product URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this code :

```
<?php echo $this->getUrl('history/detail/display',['item_id' => $item->getItemId()]); ?>
```

And add this code for redirect to product page :

```
<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl(); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Rohan. How about the file .phtml I want to show the product

Comment: As I said, It will redirect to product page.